# API Image Response to AWS S3 [PHP]

Tags: php, json, amazon-s3

I'm using a NeutrinoAPI API for watermarking images (https://www.neutrinoapi.com/api/image-watermark/)

That's working just fine, but now I need to upload the watermarked image to Amazon S3, which I use this code (https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/70eb06d98b008113ce97f6148fbea83d)

As the first API the response is a image, I don't know how to use it on the AWS API. That's how I'm doing, but it keeps uploading a 0kb file.

```
// Add it to S3
try {
    // Uploaded:
    $file = $_FILES[$json];
    $response = $s3->putObject(
        array(
            'Bucket'=>$bucketName,
            'Key' =>  $keyName,
            'ACL'    => 'public-read',
            'SourceFile' => $file                
        )
    );
```

When I use the 'file_put_contents($filename, $json);' it works, it exports the image I want, but how do I put it on the amazon $file?

Comment: Have you checked your file content before upload.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry for being rookie, first time using API

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP, what I am asking you to check, $file = $_FILES[$json]; so this really has any content or not ?

Comment: add `var_dump($file)` and paste the results to see whether it has any contents.

Comment: I've just put the content in a txt and it opens just fine, it seens like a parsing problem.

Comment: When I use the 'file_put_contents($filename, $json);' it works, it exports the imagem I want, but how do I put it on the amazon $file ?

Comment: I don't see any issue for s3 upload mechanism. If you think its the content that is causing the issue, just copy and save the same content in some file and specify the something like this 'SourceFile' => 'c:\samplefile.png' (the location of that file...manually created  by you).  check if it uploads